# Linear Algebra: Diagonalization E vectors and values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question provides following: A Matrix, and its Eigenvalues. It asks to diagonalize.
$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
  2&-2&-2\\
  3&-3&-2\\
  2&-2&-2
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
$\lambda = -2, -1, 0$

So the next step in this problem is to find the Eigenvectors corresponding to its Eigenvalues.

$(A+2I)\overrightarrow x=\overrightarrow0$ for $\lambda = -2$

Augmented Matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  4&-2&-2&0\\
  3&-1&-2&0\\
  2&-2&-0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Reduced Echelon Form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  1&0&-1&0\\
  0&1&-1&0\\
  0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\overrightarrow v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
$(A+I)\overrightarrow x=\overrightarrow0$ for $\lambda = -1$

Augmented Matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  3&-2&-2&0\\
  3&-2&-2&0\\
  2&-2&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Reduced Echelon Form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  1&0&-1&0\\
  0&1&-0.5&0\\
  0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\overrightarrow v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\\frac{1}{2}\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
$(A+0)\overrightarrow x=\overrightarrow0$ for $\lambda = 0$

Augmented Matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  2&-2&-2&0\\
  3&-3&-2&0\\
  2&-2&-2&0
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Reduced Echelon Form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  1&-1&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\overrightarrow v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
P Matrix corresponding to Eigenvectors:
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&\frac12&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
D Matrix corresponding to Eigenvalues:
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}-2&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Last step is to check if $AP = PD$

So I just did checked, and AP does = PD.. so i wasted the last 30 minutes of my time but didnt have the heart to delete this post...

Comment: $AP \ne PD$  the way you have written it.  But, you have dropped a minus sign on $D.$

Comment: what do you mean? if $AP=PD$ then A is similar to a diagonal matrix right?

Comment: You should have $-1$ and not $1$ in your representation of $D.$

Answer (score 1):

The point of this is that you can now write $A$ in diagonalised form:

$$A=PDP^{-1}$$

This is useful because it can be shown that $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$, with $D^n$ very easy to calculate.